# How to make editable TextView by website or app itself

Tags: android, web, textview

I am quite new in Android and i need to solve this problem.

How to edit (or make editable) my app.I need to daily edit TextView in app by website or only by app itself (maybe by admin in the app).

For example: App where you will daily upload new quotes.
(See the pictures to understand what i mean/need)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T72r.png) First day

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guxcs.png) Second day (I edit the TextView to another quote)

Comment: Where did you get the data is this in the local database or on the server

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cloud services for this:-

If you want to sync "Whenever data is available", you require push functionality. This can be achieved by utilizing Google Cloud Messaging, which is available for devices sporting Play Services.

If you just want to sync "whenever the user opens the app" you can use polling.

1)Check connectivity
2)You create a HTTP client and GET your messages in something that does not block your UI Thread, e.g AsyncTask doInBackground(...). If it is a very long running operation, you should use a Service instead.

3)Use the reply to Create/Remove/Update/Delete the data you stored

4)Deliver results to the UI-Thread, e.g AsyncTask onPostExecute(...)

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the text in a server and make the admin enable to edit it.

Then whenever you open the activity, simply retrieve the text from the server and load it to the textview.

Connections to the server is described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).